# the use of "while"

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Can "while" be used to link two situations that are not contary? (Other than the meaning of "at the same time")

For example,

(1) The earthquake in Korea occurred due to the earthquake in Japan.

(2) The earhquake in Japn was caused by the earthquake in India.

(1)+(2) => While the earthquake in Korea occurred due to the earthquake in Japan, the earthquake in Japan was caused by that in India.

Is the sentence above correct?

Comment: Yes. That is perfectly grammatical. However "while" in this sense is normally used with contrasting statements e.g. "While the rest of the class had found the work difficult, Wendy had achieved top marks". "While personally I would not use "while" in the case of the earthquakes, it is nonetheless grammatically correct".

Comment: ... 'Contrast' here is decided by context. "It was later found that the Elbonian seismologists had interpreted the facts wrongly. While the earthquake in Oreka _was_ triggered by the earthquake in Panaj, the earthquake in Ajnap was actually caused by that in Aidin."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. The only thing the OP's sentence doesn't do is to indicate that there was purpose to the comparison. I think that this sense of "while" is normally only used in a purposeful sense. If anyone said "The Canadian lives in the red house, while the Norwegian lives in the blue house", the listener might be expecting some inference to be drawn, or to have been drawn. If, however you replace "while" with "and", no purpose other than information is suggested. Have I got that right?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. As I intended to give example setences that are not a constrasting case(not even a related case), I would like to follow WS2's advice. Thanks again.